# How to get the current fragment in a Preference Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I've implemented an NFC scanner and when a tag is scanned the `onNewIntent` method gets called successfully, like so:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    resolveIntent(intent);
}
```

In `resolveIntent` I want to update the UI based on the scanned tag. The problem is that I can't figure out how to get a reference to the fragment.

I thought that I could use the `isValidFragment` method to get a hold of the fragment, but with no luck so far:

```
protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {

    if (fragmentName != null && !fragmentName.equals("")) {
        Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFragment); // this is always null
        if (f != null && f instanceof MyFragment)
            myFragment = (MyFragment) f;
    }

    return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || MyFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
}
```

So, basically the only thing I need is a reference to the current fragment, then I need to check if it is `MyFragment`, and then just to call a method that updates the UI.

I found a few similar questions, but I still can't figure it out. I also tried using an interface and make a callback, but I still don't know how to reference the fragment.

**EDIT**: This is the `pref_headers.xml` file:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header
        android:fragment=".SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment"
        android:title="@string/pref_header_general" />
    <header
        android:fragment=".SettingsActivity$MyFragment"
        android:id="@+id/myFragment"
        android:title="Test" />
</preference-headers>
```

Comment: "getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFragment)" to use that snippet, you need to give an id to fragment element in xml file. This is the way you can get a reference from given element in xml. If you can post more information about your architecture we may find a way to achive it.

Comment: Looks like a scanner activity starts a detail activity when a successful scan. Detail activity inflate one of the 3 different fragment to show different types of objects detail in UI. Right?

Comment: @EmreAktürk I've updated my post with a snippet of the `pref_headers.xml` file. I've put the id of the fragment there but it doesn't seem to be recognized.

Answer (score 3):

On `PreferenceActivity`, override method `onAttachFragment`. There you can get reference to the fragment when is clicked.

```
    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Header class is not extending Fragment. So this is the why you always get null object. You are trying to cast an object to another one that cannot polymorph or trying to find a view the way of fragment.

Open DDMS and try to dump View Hiearchy to understand how PreferenceActivity works. Looks like it parses the given xml and inflates another view components build the UI.

Maybe you can give it a try to findViewById or load different preference xml files to change UI.

Comment: Even tought, i dont think header has "class" tag to behaive it. It may not load your fragment :/ But i am not sure about this.

Answer (score -1):

When you initialize fragment you can set Tag to fragment like this

```
mFT = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mFT.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "myFragment");
mFT.commit();
```

and then when you want to check the fragment you can get it by Tag

```
if (fragmentName != null && !fragmentName.equals("")) {
    Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myFragment");
    if (f != null && f instanceof MyFragment)
        myFragment = (MyFragment) f;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I don't really initialize it, instead I've used the `pref_headers.xml` file, as in Google's example.

Comment: then second option could be to check your imports `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` replace it with `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: I think Header class is not extending Fragment. So this is the why you always get null object. Open DDMS and try to search around UI to understand how PreferenceActivity works. Looks like it parses the given xml and inflates another view components build the UI.